# Google Cloud Functions GitHub auto-deployer says: The request has errors

Tags: github, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I have installed the [GitHub auto-deployer](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer) for Google Cloud Functions, but when I now push my function into my GitHub repository, I receive an abstract error message `"The request has errors"` with the following rather non-descript details. What could specifically be going wrong here?

```
E      githubAutoDeployer  [CODE]  2017-12-30 19:19:37.362  
Failed to create function projects/[MY_BUCKET]/locations/us-central/functions/[MY_FUNCTION] { Error: The request has errors
at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
code: 400,
errors:
[ { message: 'The request has errors',                                                               
    domain: 'global',                                          
    reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
E      githubAutoDeployer  [CODE]  2017-12-30 19:19:37.363  Error: The request has errors
at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
D      githubAutoDeployer  [CODE]  2017-12-30 19:19:37.365  
Function execution took 2319 ms, finished with status code: 500
```

**UPDATE** The mentioning of `google-auth-library` in the stack trace made me think that something may be wrong with my credentials. But the output from `gcloud auth list` appears alright:

```
Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       [MY_ID]@gmail.com
```

**UPDATE** What is perhaps slightly unconventional is that I have `"path":"",` in my `config.json`. But then my `index.js` resides directly at the top of my repository, so there is no path to specify.

**UPDATE** [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer/auto-deployer/index.js#L137-L151) is where the error from Google Cloud Functions is passed on by `githubAutoDeployer` (unfortunately source code for the  upstream server is apparently not available):

```
gcf.projects.locations.functions.create({ resource, location }, (err, operation) => {
  if (err && err.errors && err.errors[0] && err.errors[0].reason === 'alreadyExists') {
    // ...
  } else if (err) {
    console.error(`Failed to create function ${resource.name}`, err);
    reject(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was that I was specifying `"location" : "us-central"` instead of `us-central1` (which [supports Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/)) in my `config.json`.

I found out by sending a raw POST request to the [Google Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/) (after obtaining a service account and access token, etc.). At this level the API returns a clear error indication:

```
"fieldViolations": [
  {
    "field": "region",
    "description": "region us-central is not supported."
  }
]
```

Apparently and unfortunately this does not enter any of the log files when `githubAutoDeployer` attempts the same call.