# Google Cloud Functions GitHub auto-deployer says: service timeout

Tags: github, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

After overcoming a [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037299/google-cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer-says-the-request-has-errors) with the Google Cloud Functions GitHub auto-deployer, I am now observing this error reported by GitHub for its webhook:

```
We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout
```

Is it correct to assume that the since GitHub's maximum webhook timeout period was [shortened to 10 seconds](https://developer.github.com/changes/2017-09-12-changes-to-maximum-webhook-timeout-period/) back in September, it is now simply too short for successfully deploying Google Cloud Functions? If so, can `githubAutoDeployer` still serve in any reliable manner?

The following indication obtained when deploying functions "manually" with `gcloud beta functions deploy` seems relevant:

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume that the since GitHub's maximum webhook timeout period was shortened to 10 seconds back in September, it is now simply too short for successfully deploying Google Cloud Functions?

Yes.

> If so, can githubAutoDeployer still serve in any reliable manner?

No, considering it is a synchronous process which aims at [(`auto-deployer/index.js`) returning  the result for each deployment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer/auto-deployer/index.js#L266-L276).
You would need to rewrite the `index.js` in order for the process to be asychronous, returning immediately but losing the deployment status.